# How 'Update' functionality works in android mobile applications?

Tags: android, mobile-application

I am working on android mobile application, in which I am using xml for displaying the data and the application also have images. When first time I will generated apk and will installed it, it will work fine.
My problem is updating the application. 
I have data in database on the server and also have images in separate directory. When I will update the application I want the data from the database and images from the server. For that I will generate xml which contains the values of database tables.

Here my question is that, Is it possible to overwrite the existing xml with the new one in the mobile application and also add images from the server to the mobile?

The logic behind it, the user will use this application offline.

I don't want to use the database in the application.

Below is the sample xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<projects>
    <list>
        <project1>
            <name>Project1</name>
        </project1>
        <project2>Project2</project2>
        .
        .
        .
    </list>
</projects>
```

If I choose project1 then it will display data from the related xml of the project1 i.e. project1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<project1>
    <overview>some text here</overview>
    <amenities>
        <amenity1>
            <title>Title1</title>
            <description>Some text here</description>
        </amenity1>
        <images>
            <sample1>Image Path</sample1>
            <sample2>Image Path</sample2>
        </images>
        .
        .
        .
    </amenities>
</project1>
```

In the above examples 1st xml is the list of all projects. The 2nd example is the related xml for every project.
Now when I update the app then it will replace new updated xmls or add new xmls in the application.
Is this possible? And also, is it possible to download the new images at the time of update?

Answer (score 1):

When you update an application - by increasing the version number and publishing in market - the apk file in the user's mobile gets replaced by your latest one. Thus if you have changed the code such that it uses some new xml for retrieving data, it should work. For the database, if you have incremented the database version number, the `onUpgrade()` method in `SQLiteOpenHelper` class will be called, where you can modify the database also, as required.

**Edit** (answering to editted question):

> Now when I update the app then it will replace new updated xmls or add new xmls in the application. Is this possible?

Like I mentioned above, if you have a new version of the apk which has your new xmls, then when update is done by a user, his app will have your new xmls. But what I'm saying is,  you'll probably need to change your code so that it can parse and handle the new image paths from server and all.

> is it possible to download the new images at the time of update?

This is not possible at the time of update. Once your app is opened, however, you can probably call some function which will read and parse your xml, and start pulling images and data from your server.

Comment: Thanks Aswin, I don't want to change the code, I just want the new record from my server database and store it in xml format in the application so I can fetch and display it from jquery, here I am using Jquery mobile features. I don't want to use local database. What about the images?

Comment: Tell me this, what do you mean by updating the application?

Comment: Updating means, only retrieve the latest records from the live server database and the new updated images.

Comment: Your scenario is not very clear from the question. Can you explain what exactly this 'xml' is that you are using (paste sample code), and how you are using it to display the data?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the UI part of your app that uses XML except by updating your app from the play store (or an alternate store).

You can pass data in the form of XML or JSON from your server to your app. You can parse this data and will have to create some form of a persistence layer to store it (this would be a local database or something).

You can then retrieve this data from your local db and use it however you like.

Comment: Thanks Anup, here i don't want to change the UI, I just want the new record from my server database and store it in xml format in the application so I can fetch and display it from jquery, here I am using Jquery mobile features. I don't want to use local database.